# Prolog Difference Of Squares

Tags: prolog, clpfd, instantiation-error

I want to find difference between square of a+1 and square of a is 2a+1 in prolog. For this reason i wrote code like this:

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).

kare(X,Y):- Y #= X*X.

abc(A,B,F) :-
        kare(A,P),
        kare(B,T), 
        F is P-T.
```

I tried it with

```
?- abc(D,E,P).

ERROR: is/2: Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated.
```

Anyone help me with this problem.

Comment: Please ask a new question for a completely different topic. Please revert this to your earlier question, and accept the answer you were given. You should not modify your question to become something totally different.

Comment: i cannot ask it it says wait 3 days

Comment: Please revert your changes, accept the answer, and *then* ask a new question.

Answer (score 3):

You get the error because you are using is/2, which expects the arguments to be bound. But in your example query the arguments `D`, `E` and `P` are unbound variables therefore `P` and `T` are unbound as well when you get to the goal with is/2. Since you are already using clpfd, use #=/2 instead:

```
abc(A,B,F) :-
   kare(A,P),
   kare(B,T),
   F #= P-T.    % <- here
```

That way your query yields a result:

```
   ?- abc(D,E,P).
D^2#=_A,
_A in 0..sup,
P+_B#=_A,
_B in 0..sup,
E^2#=_B
```

Comment: okey how can find **  find difference between square of a+1 and square of a is 2a+1**

Comment: @dymayd: I'm not sure if I understand correctly what you mean by *difference between square of a+1 and square of a is 2a+1*. Looking at your predicate abc/3 my guess would be that you might like to query something like: `?- D #= A+1, E #= 2*A+1, abc(D,E,P).` or maybe with a concrete value for `A`: `?- A #= 2, D #= A+1, E #= 2*A+1, abc(D,E,P).` Can you provide some examples with the results you expect?